# can I know what data is currently stored in Google Fit?

Tags: android, google-fit

I read Google Fit documentation multiple times, and checked number of applications that are integrated with Google Fit. Yet I am not sure what each app store in Google Fit store!

Can I view **all** the available data currently in Google Fit store? dashboard or similar? is there a way to do that?

For example: runkeeper app is connected to Google Fit, but I couldn't identify what kind of data it provides and what kind of data it accesses and retrieves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the [Fittler](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.spire.fitviewer) app is useful to you.

Comment: Awesome, that's what I need. Thank you!